# account has two projects but only one in listed in bigquery console

Tags: google-bigquery

The "Switch to project" popup only lists one of my two projects. If I click "manage projects" I see both of my projects. I have tried logging out and back in. Am looking for ideas. It there some project setting that makes it available in BigQuery?

Comment: what do you mean by"my projects". are they both where you are a member of project or second one is just where you have access to some datasets?

Comment: Is BigQuery API enabled on the second project?